# How to compute $\int x^2 e^x\ dx$ using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

For the integral below, and in integration by parts in general, I am unsure which to know with certainty which is the right variable to set? What is the differential and the integral in this problem?

\begin{equation}
\int x^{2} e^{x} d x
\end{equation}

Edit so here is my process so far:

\begin{equation}
\text { Let } u=x^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text { Let } \frac{d v}{d x}=e^{x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Hence: } \\
\left(x^{2}\right)\left(e^{x}\right)-\int 2 x e^{x} d x
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since there is another term not being like and multiplied together we again use integration by parts

\begin{equation}
\left(x^{2}\right)\left(e^{x}\right)-\left[(2 x)\left(e^{x}\right)-\int 2 e^{x} d x\right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^{2} e^{x}-\left[2 x e^{x}-2 e^{x}\right]+c
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried so we can better help you.

Comment: Welcome here! Please tell us what you tried. There are only a few obvious choices for $u$ and $v$ to try. Which one did you try? Did it work? Why not?

Comment: I set u to the exponential and the differential to be x^2 however I feel like this makes this far more complicated and from looking at it there is going to be another integration by parts to fully solve the question

Comment: $x^2$, and in general polynomials, become simpler (their degrees decrease) when differentiated. On the other hand $e^x$ remains unaltered when integrated (and differentiated). In integration by parts $\int f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx$ one factor (the $f$) gets differentiated, and the other ($g(x)$) gets integrated. This suggests to pick $f(x)=x^2$ to be the one that will get differentiated, and $g(x)=e^x$ the one that gets integrated.

Comment: $u=x^2$ could be a good choice. You haven't told us which variable, $u$ or $v$, you will differentiate, and which one you will integrate.

Comment: Do you know what $\int x e^x\ dx$ is?

Comment: @user85667: please write this as an answer

Comment: @Taladris so as user85667 said I will integrate the exponential and differentiate the polynomial. I will put it out on the edit section

Comment: So I believe I have the solution or i am at least very close to it, thanks guys for your help

Comment: Look up tabular integration. It is specifically for integrals of this form and avoids the use of multiple iterations of integration by parts.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have never heard of this form of integration, i will check it out. We're taught at my academic level just to use parts but other forms of solving the problem are valid

Comment: The secret is $e^x$ is not changed after integration or derivative, so you can reduce power of $x$ to $0$, and you did it right way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can first try pushing the $e^x$ into $dx$. Like that.

$\int x^{2} e^{x} d x = \int x^{2}  d e^{x} $

Then do the integration by part.

$= x^{2} e^{x} - \int e^{x}  d x^{2}  = x^{2} e^{x} - \int 2xe^{x}  d x$

You can see $x^2$ become $x$ inside the integral, so you are on the right path. Do integration by part once again, you can find the solution.

There is no absolute rule which expression to push into $dx$. Which you meet new kind of question, you can do it by try and error, then you will earn experience about it. Usually, you can try $e^x$ first, then $sinx, cosx$. Polynomials are usually not good since the degree will become higher.

Comment: I think I am very close if not have gotten the full solution to my question, thank you for the guidance and the clue

Answer (score 0):

The general equation for integration by parts is
$$
\int u\frac{dv}{dx} dx = uv - \int v \frac{du}{dx} dx
$$
Setting $u = x^2$ and $\frac{dv}{dx} = e^x$, we get
$$
\int x^2e^x dx = x^2e^x - \int e^x (2x) dx \\
= x^2e^x - 2\int xe^x  dx \\
=x^2e^x - 2(xe^x - e^x) + c\\
=x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x + c
$$
and you can verify by taking the derivative of the above expression and getting $x^2e^x$.